# How can I reuse a class instance for a newtype?

Tags: class, haskell

I have defined a type called `Natural` which is an positive integer that includes 0:

```
newtype Natural = Natural Integer
    deriving (Eq, Ord)
instance Show Natural where
  show (Natural i) = show i

toNatural :: (Integral i) => i -> Natural
toNatural x | x < 0     = error "Natural cannot be negative"
            | otherwise = Natural $ toInteger x

fromNatural :: Natural -> Integer
fromNatural (Natural i) = i

instance Num Natural where
    fromInteger = toNatural
    x + y       = toNatural (fromNatural x + fromNatural y)
    x - y       = let r = fromNatural x - fromNatural y in
                      if r < 0 then error "Subtraction yielded a negative value"
                               else toNatural r
    x * y       = toNatural (fromNatural x * fromNatural y)
    abs x       = x
    signum x    = toNatural $ signum $ fromNatural x

instance Enum Natural where
  toEnum = toNatural . toInteger
  fromEnum = fromInteger . fromNatural
```

In my code it is common with `newtype`s that take a `Natural` as parameter. And since I want these types to be instances of `Num` and `Enum`, I find myself reimplementing the same classes over and over:

```
newtype NodeId
    = NodeId Natural
    deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

instance Num NodeId where
    fromInteger = NodeId . toNatural
    (NodeId x) + (NodeId y) = NodeId (x + y)
    (NodeId x) - (NodeId y) = NodeId (x - y)
    (NodeId x) * (NodeId y) = NodeId (x * y)
    abs (NodeId x) = NodeId (abs x)
    signum (NodeId x) = NodeId (signum x)

instance Enum NodeId where
  toEnum = NodeId . toEnum
  fromEnum (NodeId x) = fromEnum x

...

newtype InstructionId = InstructionId Natural
  deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Num InstructionId where
    fromInteger = InstructionId . toNatural
    (InstructionId x) + (InstructionId y) = InstructionId (x + y)
    (InstructionId x) - (InstructionId y) = InstructionId (x - y)
    (InstructionId x) * (InstructionId y) = InstructionId (x * y)
    abs (InstructionId x) = InstructionId (abs x)
    signum (InstructionId x) = InstructionId (signum x)

instance Enum InstructionId where
  toEnum = InstructionId . toEnum
  fromEnum (InstructionId x) = fromEnum x

...

newtype PatternId = PatternId Natural
  deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Num PatternId where
    fromInteger = PatternId . toNatural
    (PatternId x) + (PatternId y) = PatternId (x + y)
    (PatternId x) - (PatternId y) = PatternId (x - y)
    (PatternId x) * (PatternId y) = PatternId (x * y)
    abs (PatternId x) = PatternId (abs x)
    signum (PatternId x) = PatternId (signum x)

instance Enum PatternId where
  toEnum = PatternId . toEnum
  fromEnum (PatternId x) = fromEnum x
```

As you see these implementations are almost identical, which made me wonder whether I could implement some class `A` that would itself implement the `Num` and `Enum` classes, and then for each `newtype` I would only need to implement some simple function (maybe not any function at all) of `A`. But I'm not sure how to do that or whether it's even possible at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: The type should be declared as `newtype Natural = Natural { unNatural :: Integer }`. (sorry, could not resist ;-) )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an extension called [GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/deriving.html#id3175392) that you can use for the same end. It lets you "carry over" definitions from the underlying type to the newtype.

Here's a small, contrived code example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

newtype Foo = Foo Integer deriving (Show, Eq, Num)\
```

It's a bit confusing though: standard derived classes like `Show` and `Eq` will still be derived the normal way. So `Foo`'s `Show` instance is different from `Integer`'s. However, all other classes get carried through directly, so `Foo`'s `Num` instances is the same as `Integer`'s.

You have to be a little careful with it because it [does not always play well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17137111/why-isnt-generalizednewtypederiving-a-safe-haskell) with certain Haskell extensions. However, for the simple `Num` case, it's a perfectly good option. I also believe that upcoming versions of GHC are fixing some of the common problems with `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`, so it should become a much safer extension in the near future.

Comment: Cool! This removed all that ugly duplicated code! =D

Comment: GHC 7.8 will have the Role system which fixes holes in GND. In particular, they go from being compiler bugs to library designer bugs—the library designer must choose whether or not their exposed types should be GND-applicable.